# JavaScript to change a multi level <select> into accordion

Tags: javascript, jquery, accordion, osclass, bootstrap-accordion

in my item post page, their is an   for selecting main category and than after selecting it shows relevant sub category.
i want to change this  in to a accordion. please help me how to change this. so when a user come to my website and try to post ad he should be shown accordion for selecting the main category and sub category. please help me to achieve this by modify the code or using java-script to achieve this.

the code `

```
    $categoryID = Params::getParam('catId');
    if( osc_item_category_id() != null ) {
        $categoryID = osc_item_category_id();
    }

    if( Session::newInstance()->_getForm('catId') != '' ) {
        $categoryID = Session::newInstance()->_getForm('catId');
    }

    $subcategoryID = '';
    if( !Category::newInstance()->isRoot($categoryID) ) {
        $subcategoryID = $categoryID;
        $category      = Category::newInstance()->findRootCategory($categoryID);
        $categoryID    = $category['pk_i_id'];
    }

    if($categories == null) {
        if(View::newInstance()->_exists('categories')) {
            $categories = View::newInstance()->_get('categories');
        } else {
            $categories = osc_get_categories();
        }
    }

    if ($item == null) { $item = osc_item(); }

    $subcategory = array();
    ?>
<select id="parentCategory" name="parentCatId">
    <option value=""><?php _e('Select a category', 'modern'); ?></option>
    <?php foreach($categories as $_category) {
    $selected = ( (isset($item["fk_i_category_id"]) && $item["fk_i_category_id"] == $_category['pk_i_id']) || (isset($categoryID) && $categoryID == $_category['pk_i_id']) );
    if($selected) { $subcategory = $_category; };
    echo '<option value="'.$_category['pk_i_id'].'" '.($selected ? 'selected="selected"' : '' ).'>'.$_category['s_name'].'</option>';
} ?>
</select>
<select id="catId" name="catId">
    <?php
    if(!empty($subcategory)) {
        if( count($subcategory['categories']) > 0 ) {
            echo '<option value="">'.__('Select Subcategory', 'modern').'</option>'; 
            foreach($subcategory['categories'] as $c) {
                $selected = ( (isset($item["fk_i_category_id"]) && $item["fk_i_category_id"] == $c['pk_i_id']) || (isset($subcategoryID) && $subcategoryID == $c['pk_i_id']) );
                echo '<option value="'.$c['pk_i_id'].'" '.($selected ? 'selected="selected"' : '' ).'>'.$c['s_name'].'</option>';
            }
        } else {
            echo '<option value="'.$categoryID.'" >'._e('No Subcategory', 'modern').'</option>';
        }
    } else {
        echo '<option value="">'._e('Select Subcategory', 'modern').'</option>';
    }
    ?>
</select>
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
        <?php
        foreach($categories as $c) {
            if( count($c['categories']) > 0 ) {
                $subcategory = array();
                for($i = 0; $i < count($c['categories']); $i  ) {
                    $subcategory[] = array($c['categories'][$i]['pk_i_id'], $c['categories'][$i]['s_name']);
                }
                printf('var categories_%1$s = %2$s;', $c['pk_i_id'], json_encode($subcategory));
                echo PHP_EOL;
            }
        }
        ?>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $("#parentCategory").bind('change', function(){
            var categoryID = $(this).val();
            if( categoryID == 0 ) {
                var options = '<option value="'   categoryID   '" selected=""><?php _e('No Subcategory', 'modern'); ?></option>';
            }
            categories = window['categories_'   categoryID];
            if( categories==null || !$.isArray(categories) ) {
                var options = '<option value="'   categoryID   '" selected=""><?php _e('No Subcategory', 'modern'); ?></option>';
            } else {
                var options = '<option value="'   categoryID   '" selected=""><?php _e('Select Subcategory', 'modern'); ?>...</option>';
                $.each(categories, function(index, value){
                    options  = '<option value="'   value[0]   '">'   value[1]   '</option>';
                });
            };
            $('#catId').html(options);
            $("#catId").next("a").find(".select-box-label").text('Select a Sub Category...');
            $("#catId").change();
            $("div#uniform-catId.selector").css('visibility', 'visible');
        });

         // In case of error and Category already chosen, let's show the Subcategory selector
        if($("div#uniform-parentCategory.selector select").val()) {
            $("div#uniform-catId.selector").css('visibility', 'visible');
        }
    });

</script>
<?php
}
```

?>`

Answer (score 0):

If this is related to osclass, in item-post.php from bender (for example), use

```
<?php ItemForm::category_select(null, null, __('Select a category', 'bender')); ?>
```

instead of

```
<?php ItemForm::category_multiple_selects(); ?>
```

PS. This is not a js solution.

Comment: i want to change the one u said or i mentioned as a accordion . that means user click main category and the sub category slide out like vise all category

Comment: I missunderstood then. But what is the problem with the functionality as it is now? You chose 1st level category. If it has subcategories, a second dropdown is shown, and so on.  Or as my solution suggests, all categories in a single dropdown.

Comment: their is no problem with functionality, i want to make user experience even more easier, to show all the available main category and the user can click the main category and the sub slide out....so it will be more user friendly. so want to change this select drop down into a accordion